# AnsibleModule object is not callable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-inventory

My playbook is as follows

```
---
- hosts: nodes
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Run Shell Script to get IPs with 4xx and 5xx errors

    script: /home/ubuntu/ips.sh
    args:
      chdir: /home/ubuntu
    register: ips

  - set_fact:
       iperrors: "{{ groups.nodes | map('extract', hostvars, 'ips') | map(attribute='stdout') | join('') }}"
    run_once: true
    delegate_to: localhost


  - name: Python Custom Module to get Top 5 Ips
    5ips:
      iperrors: "{{iperrors}}"
    run_once: true
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: 5ip
```

I have written a custom module 5ips But when I execute playbook it throws an error as follows

```
TASK [Python Custom Module to get Top 5 Ips] ***************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: 'AnsibleModule' object is not callable
fatal: [54.183.110.130 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1545815995.35-86175850009970/AnsiballZ_5ips.py\", line 113, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1545815995.35-86175850009970/AnsiballZ_5ips.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1545815995.35-86175850009970/AnsiballZ_5ips.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_5ips_payload_7Vi28k/__main__.py\", line 41, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_5ips_payload_7Vi28k/__main__.py\", line 12, in main\nTypeError: 'AnsibleModule' object is not callable\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc"
```

my 5ips.py is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

def main():
    fields = {
        "iperrors" :{"required":True, "type":"str"}
        }
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec = fields)
    iperrors = module.params['iperrors']
    module(iperrors)

    if IpList !=0:
        module.exit_json(changed = True, msg = "top5 ips done")
    else:
        module.fail_json(changed = False, Error = "Something went wrong in Top5IPS.py")

def module(iperrors):
    ipErrors ={}
    IpList=[]
```

the input iperrors im giving is a multiline string. Im not sure exactly where the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "module_stderr" key in the output. Near the end it says "'AnsibleModule' object is not callable\n"

I'm not super familiar with custom ansible modules, but it looks like the way to write them has changed, check the new docs here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#developing-modules-general

Alternatively, you could try using an older (<2.0, probably) version of ansible.